# ASP.NET Photo Upload

Tags: asp.net

When uploading a photo to my server using the following code, I'm receiving an erroneous value. This is working fine in the debug mode and when published in localhost.

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"), date);

if (!Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads")))
{      
       Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"));
}

file.SaveAs(filePath);
```

Can someone please point out what I've done incorrectly?

Comment: How do you Upload the file without using FileUpload control?

Answer (score 0):

ok I am assuming that you are using File Upload control or you can use the below sample code if you want to use the FileUpload control in your asp.net page.

1. Add the FileUpload control (Here im adding ajax async FileUpload control and named as asyncFileUpload.
2. Write A Method and Call it whenever you want.

   public int AsyncFileUpload()

   ```
   {
       string xlsFile = AsyncFileUpload1.FileName;
       if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
       {
           string FileName = Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
           string Extension = Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

           string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + FileName);
           if (Extension == ".doc")//check the file extension here
           {
               AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
           }
       }
   }
   ```